# Таймер, без паузы

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram, время

Я пишу telegram бота на aiogram (Python). Мне нужен секундомер или таймер который будет работать при команде /game. Но при этом не останавливал другие команды например /start. Есть такие модули ? Помогите пожалуйста! Заранее спасибо!

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
  bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет')
  
@bot.message_handler(commands=['game'])
def send_game(message):
  for q in range(60):
    time.sleep(1)
    i += 1
    if i == 10:
      await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Осталось 30 секунд')
```

Comment: Как минимум, в асинхронном коде не должно быть `time.sleep(1)`, используйте `await asyncio.sleep(1)` вместо этого. Ну и send_game должен быть асинхронной функцией, раз уж вы в нем используете `await`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот ответ:

```
import asyncio

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def send_welcome(message):
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['game'])
async def send_game(message):
    i = 0
    for q in range(60):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        i += 1
        if i == 10:
            await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Осталось 30 секунд')
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]